# Paypal ExpressCheckout "constant values" to validate a successful transaction

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

In `SetExpressCheckout` I have the following values set

```
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD' => 'InstantPaymentOnly',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION'=> 'Sale'
```

After a successful `DoExpressCheckout`, this is some of what is returned

```
ACK => Success
PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE => expresscheckout
PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE => instant
PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS => Completed
PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE => 0
PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK => Success
```

**PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS** -- With `InstantPaymentOnly` set, will `DoExpressCheckout` ever return a `PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS` of `In-Progress`, `Pending`, `Processed` or something other than a clear yes or no as to the success?

Basically, since only instant payments are allowed, the only payments that will *ever* complete will have a `PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS` of `Completed` the first time around?

**ACK** and **PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK** -- Are they linked? Paypal states that `ACK` "*Indicates the Success or Failure status of the transaction and whether any warnings were returned*."

Both `ACK` values will either be `Success` or `Failure`? Does that refer explicitly to whether or not the transaction was or will be completed?

Much appreciated,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InstantPaymentOnly blocks non-instant funding sources in buyer accounts (such as echeck payments). This means that you will not get transactions that are waiting on buyer funds movements to complete. But there are other factors which could cause a payment to be pending rather than complete. These other factors may or may not apply to your specific use case, but examples include payments made to you in a new currency which would be held until you decide whether to open a balance in that currency or auto-convert them to your primary currency, or certain fraud filter/fraud detection scenarios.

As for ACK/ACK_PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK, for cases where you are only requesting the one payment (and no additional things like billing agreement signup) I would guess the two statuses will always be equal, but I would advise you to verify with the official documentation.